# CustomValidator control not working in .Net

Tags: .net, validation, customvalidator

I have a rather large ASPX form with lots of textboxes and drop down lists to fill in.  Most of the textboxes have RequiredFieldValidator controls and these work just fine.

However, I have 3 textboxes for Home, Mobile and Work Telephone numbers.  Each textbox is optional but if it is filled in, then the value must be numeric.  I don't need to validate the format of the phone number at this point, only ensure that it is numeric.

The client side code for one of the fields looks like so:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblWorkPhone" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtWorkPhone" Text="<%$ Resources: Registration, WorkPhone %>" /><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWorkPhone" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="validateWorkPhone" runat="server" 
                            ValidationGroup="reg" ControlToValidate="txtWorkPhone" ForeColor="Red" 
                            ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources: Registration, HomePhoneNumber %>" 
                            Text="<%$ Resources: Registration, RequireMessage %>" 
                            onservervalidate="validateWorkPhone_ServerValidate" />
```

The server side validation method is here :

```
protected void validateWorkPhone_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    long temp = 0;

    long.TryParse(txtWorkPhone.Text, out temp);

    if (temp == 0)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        validateWorkPhone.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
        validateWorkPhone.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell the server side validation method is not firing at all.  All the other validation controls on the page do seem to work fine.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `txtWorkPhone` control to the `reg` ValidationGroup?

Comment: Yes I tried that too and it made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the client-side validators (such as the RequiredFieldValidators) valid? The server-side validators only fire when all the client-side ones are valid.

**EDIT**
Most validators, such as RequiredFieldValidator or RegularExpressionValidator, perform the validation both client-side and server side. When the client-side validation fails, the submit is cancelled so a server-side-only validation doesn't fire.

For a CustomValidator you will have to add a client-side validation explicitly, if you want that.

Comment: I am not using any client side validation

Comment: A RequiredFieldValidator performs client-side validation natively, so your CustomValidator won't fire unless all your other validators pass.

Comment: Thanks SouthShoreAK, that was it.  The validation only kicks off once all the other forms have validated also.  Its not ideal as I was hoping to get all the validation messages in one go, but it works now. Thanks again!

Comment: RegularExpressionValidators would fire at the same time as your RequiredFieldValidators, getting you everything in one go. I don't want to be pushy, I'm just trying to save you some code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only need to validate that they are numeric, why not use a RegexValidator instead? It would save you a trip to the server.

[MSDN article on the above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx), with list of common regex's, including a numeric one.

Comment: I thought RegEx would force me to have a value.  These fields are optional so should only be validated if a value is entered.

Comment: `^\d*$` should allow empty or any number of number characters

Answer (score 0):

This post is long gone, but I just had a similar problem and narrowed it down to being a .NET bug.  My custom validator was inside of a panel that I was programatically setting the visibility to false in page load and later in my code setting it to true.  To me that shouldn't make a difference, but when I set the default value of the panel to false in the .aspx file, hence never setting the visibility in code to false, it works fine.

Oddly, I have a cancel button that sets the visibility to false with no further problems.